# jstree: jquery.find working just for nodes of the first level

Tags: jquery, jstree

Why does this code not work?

http://jsfiddle.net/3q9Ma/28/

```
<div id="jstree">
    <ul>
        <li id="x1">AAA004
            <ul>
                <li id="x2">AAA005</li>
                <li>AAA006
                    <ul>
                        <li id="x3">AAA007
                            <ul>
                                <li>AAA008</li>
                                <li>AAA009</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>AAA010</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>AAA011</li>
        <li>AAA012</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#jstree').on('ready.jstree', function (e, data) {
          x = $('#jstree').find("li[id='x3']");
          alert(x[0].id);
    }).jstree();
});
```

Trying to find nodes of the first level works!!! but with others do not. Node with id="x1" will be found but node with id="x2" or id="x3" not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When page is loaded - there is no `li#x3` node in the DOM. Look at the [result](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3q9Ma/28/show/) of `jstree`. You code runs as soon as the page is loaded.

But if you open the list - yes, `li#x3` will appear and it this will happen after your code runs.

Comment: Well, I can see the id="x3" there in the tree.

Comment: If you open the list - yes, it will appears. But you code evaluate then page loaded, not then you click to open sub-list.